# No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found with custom policy based authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a custom policy based authorization handler as defined below. Authentication is handled before the user hit this application so I only need authorization. I am getting the error:

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme.

If the authorization check succeeds then I do not get the error and all is well. This error only happens when the authorization check fails. I would expect that a 401 is returned on failure.

```
public class EasRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public EasRequirement(string easBaseAddress, string applicationName, bool bypassAuthorization)
    {
        _client = GetConfiguredClient(easBaseAddress);
        _applicationName = applicationName;
        _bypassAuthorization = bypassAuthorization;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsAuthorized(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public class EasHandler : AuthorizationHandler<EasRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, EasRequirement requirement)
    {
        var mvcContext = context.Resource as ActionContext;

        bool isAuthorized;

        try
        {
            isAuthorized = requirement.IsAuthorized(mvcContext).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO: log the error?
            isAuthorized = false;
        }

        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        context.Fail();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var easBaseAddress = Configuration.GetSection("EasBaseAddress").Value;
        var applicationName = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationName").Value;
        var bypassAuthorization = bool.Parse(Configuration.GetSection("BypassEasAuthorization").Value);

        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddRequirements(new EasRequirement(easBaseAddress, applicationName, bypassAuthorization))
            .Build();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("EAS", policy);
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, EasHandler>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Authorization and authentication are closely linked in ASP.NET Core. When authorization fails, this will be passed to an authentication handler to handle the authorization failure.

So even if you don’t need actual authentication to identify your users, you will still need to set up some authentication scheme that is able to handle forbid and challenge results (403 and 401).

To do that, you need to call `AddAuthentication()` and configure a default forbid/challenge scheme:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "scheme name";

    // you can also skip this to make the challenge scheme handle the forbid as well
    options.DefaultForbidScheme = "scheme name";

    // of course you also need to register that scheme, e.g. using
    options.AddScheme<MySchemeHandler>("scheme name", "scheme display name");
});
```

`MySchemeHandler` needs to implement `IAuthenticationHandler` and in your case, you especially need to implement `ChallengeAsync` and `ForbidAsync`:

```
public class MySchemeHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
{
    private HttpContext _context;

    public Task InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());

    public Task ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public Task ForbidAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the default behavior you described? " When authorization fails, this will be passed to an authentication handler to handle the authorization failure"

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis No, that’s how authentication and authorization are linked. When the authorization fails, then an authentication scheme has to handle that failure. – What would you want to do there instead? Something has to happen.

Comment: @ajamrozek A credential prompt as in a browser popup that asks for your login? Or just a redirect to some login form? The former shouldn’t be possible and the latter is explicitly prevented by having your own authentication scheme. Maybe you should open a new question that covers what exactly you are doing. Feel free to post a link to the question here and I’ll take a look.

Comment: "Shouldn't be possible". Challenge accepted;) Turns out I had some legacy stuff that enabled WindowsAuth in the launchsettings.json. Took that out and there's no more prompt. Otherwise, this answer guided me really well.

Comment: @ajamrozek Windows auth makes sense there – glad you figured it out :)

Comment: And if anyone wonders what "do something" should look like, refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587054/106688

Answer (score 11):

For IIS/IIS Express, can just add this line instead of all of the above in the accepted answer to get the appropriate 403 response you're expecting;

```
 services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: Strange: I've had this line and still get the `No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found.` error on a production server.

Comment: I've also had a following call to `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.Ntlm);`. Will remove this now and see if this causes the error message.

Comment: Nope, didn't help either.